# How do I convert an array of hashes into a sorted hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

If I have an array of hashes, each with a day key:

```
[
    {:day=>4,:name=>'Jay'},
    {:day=>1,:name=>'Ben'},
    {:day=>4,:name=>'Jill'}
]
```

What is the best way to convert it to a hash with sorted day values as the keys:

```
{
    :1=>[{:day=>1,:name=>'Ben'}],
    :4=>[{:day=>4,:name=>'Jay'},{:day=>4,:name=>'Jill'}]
}
```

I'm using Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.1.1

Comment: Hashes by nature are not sorted. Ruby 1.9+ maintains the insertion order, so if you create a hash and insert elements based on some sort order, Ruby will maintain those. However, any subsequent elements will not be sorted, and will be appended instead. If you need to retrieve them in a certain order, you can sort the keys prior to retrieving the values, or you can maintain an array of the keys in parallel to the hash, and keep that array in the order that you want, then iterate that array, or use it with `values_at` to retrieve the values in the order you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't bother "sorting" the keys (which amounts to ordering-by-entry-time in Ruby 1.9) until I actually needed to. Then you can use `group_by`:

```
arr = [{:day=>4,:name=>'Jay'}, {:day=>1,:name=>'Ben'}, {:day=>4,:name=>'Jill'}]
arr.group_by { |a| a[:day] }
=> {4=>[{:day=>4, :name=>"Jay"}, {:day=>4, :name=>"Jill"}],
    1=>[{:day=>1, :name=>"Ben"}]}
```

Instead, sort the keys when you actually need them.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you array is called is `list`, here's one way using the `reduce` method:

```
list.reduce({}) { |hash, item|
  (hash[item[:day]] ||= []) << item; hash
}
```

Here's another using the `map` method, but you have to carry a holder variable around:

```
hash = {}
list.each { |item|
  (hash[item[:day]] ||= []) << item
}
```

Once you have the unsorted hash say in variable `foo`, you can sort it as,

```
Hash[foo.sort]
```

Comment: You should never use `map` if you are going to discard result. Use `each` instead!

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:

```
data = [
    {:day=>4,:name=>'Jay'},
    {:day=>1,:name=>'Ben'},
    {:day=>4,:name=>'Jill'}
]

#expected solution
sol = {
    1=>[{:day=>1,:name=>'Ben'}],
    4=>[{:day=>4,:name=>'Jay'},{:day=>4,:name=>'Jill'}]
}

res = {}
data.each{|h|
  res[h[:day]] ||=  [] 
  res[h[:day]] << h
}

p res
p res == sol    #check value
p res.keys == sol.keys  #check order
```

Problem with this solution: The hash is not sorted as requested. (Same problem has [Anurags solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8956977/676874)).

So you must modify the answer a bit:

```
res = {}
data.sort_by{|h| h[:day]}.each{|h|
  res[h[:day]] ||=  [] 
  res[h[:day]] << h
}

p res
p res == sol    #check value
p res.keys == sol.keys  #check order
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails you can use `OrderedHash`:

```
ActiveSupport::OrderedHash[arr.group_by { |a| a[:day] }.sort_by(&:first)]
```

**Update:** In fact in Ruby 1.9 hash is ordered, so using `ActiveSupport` extension is not required:

```
Hash[arr.group_by { |a| a[:day] }.sort_by(&:first)]
```